# How do I debug a USB mouse connected via hub and switch?

Tags: kernel, usb, mouse

I just upgraded my os and my mouse stopped working. It used to work with openSUSE 42.1, but now not with 42.3. If I plug it directly into a USB2.0 connection, all is well, but the same mouse in a hub and switch does not. Everything enumerates just fine via "lsusb". The keyboard, SD card reader and track pad work fine. All four work fine when switched over to OS/X. And, as noted, it all worked with 42.1. So, it is kernel software.

I'd like to know what to do to debug it. The message "No input driver specified, ignoring this device." gives me pause, but it seems to go on and load "libinit" and that driver emits comforting messages. NOTE: I have used several different USB mice and they all work plugged into a port directly, but do not work when plugged in via the hub/switch. I prefer having only one mouse on my desk. :)

Here is the plugin data from Xorg.0.log:

```
[ 14199.035] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 14199.035] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 14199.035] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 14199.140] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/event2)
[ 14199.140] (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 14199.140] (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 14199.140] (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[ 14199.140] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400'
[ 14199.140] (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: always reports core events
[ 14199.141] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[ 14199.141] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 14199.196] (II) input device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[ 14199.196] (II) Device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400' set to 800 DPI
[ 14199.196] (II) input device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
[ 14199.232] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/0003:046D:C245.0010/input/input22/event2"
[ 14199.232] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Gaming Mouse G400" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[ 14199.233] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[ 14199.233] (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[ 14199.233] (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 14199.233] (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 14199.288] (II) input device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[ 14199.288] (II) Device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400' set to 800 DPI
[ 14199.288] (II) input device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
```

==== Edit 1

Per request, the usbmon output spanning a momentary unplug. The mouse is bus 2 device 7 and the keyboard is 2:4:

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/2u            
ffff8806e233f700 1861405536 C Ii:2:004:1 0:8 8 = 00000000 00000000
ffff8806e233f700 1861405602 S Ii:2:004:1 -115:8 8 <
ffff88081ba0c000 1865368758 C Ii:2:002:1 0:2048 1 = 04
ffff88081ba0c000 1865368771 S Ii:2:002:1 -115:2048 1 <
ffff880667d9b400 1865368809 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff880667d9b400 1865369024 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 00010100
ffff880667d9b400 1865369044 S Co:2:002:0 s 23 01 0010 0002 0000 0
ffff880667d9b400 1865369222 C Co:2:002:0 0 0
ffff880667d9b400 1865369236 S Co:2:002:0 s 23 03 0016 0002 0000 0
ffff880667d9b400 1865369395 C Co:2:002:0 0 0
ffff8807976d6600 1865370024 C Ii:2:006:1 -108:1 0
ffff88081ba0c000 1867673019 C Ii:2:002:1 0:2048 1 = 04
ffff88081ba0c000 1867673035 S Ii:2:002:1 -115:2048 1 <
ffff88081ba0c000 1867929050 C Ii:2:002:1 0:2048 1 = 04
ffff88081ba0c000 1867929060 S Ii:2:002:1 -115:2048 1 <
ffff88081ba0c000 1868185084 C Ii:2:002:1 0:2048 1 = 04
ffff88081ba0c000 1868185094 S Ii:2:002:1 -115:2048 1 <
ffff88081ba0c000 1868441108 C Ii:2:002:1 0:2048 1 = 04
ffff88081ba0c000 1868441121 S Ii:2:002:1 -115:2048 1 <
ffff88081ba0c000 1868697138 C Ii:2:002:1 0:2048 1 = 04
ffff88081ba0c000 1868697148 S Ii:2:002:1 -115:2048 1 <
ffff88081ba0c000 1868953166 C Ii:2:002:1 0:2048 1 = 04
ffff88081ba0c000 1868953176 S Ii:2:002:1 -115:2048 1 <
ffff88066bc17900 1868955522 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff88066bc17900 1868955693 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 01010100
ffff88066bc17900 1868955733 S Co:2:002:0 s 23 01 0010 0002 0000 0
ffff88066bc17900 1868955869 C Co:2:002:0 0 0
ffff88066809d900 1868985881 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff88066809d900 1868986113 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 01010000
ffff880659263a00 1869017936 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff880659263a00 1869018143 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 01010000
ffff88062e929400 1869049931 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff88062e929400 1869050150 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 01010000
ffff88062e929400 1869081943 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff88062e929400 1869082181 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 01010000
ffff880669fba600 1869082364 S Co:2:002:0 s 23 03 0004 0002 0000 0
ffff880669fba600 1869095631 C Co:2:002:0 0 0
ffff880669fba600 1869109915 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff880669fba600 1869110129 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 03011000
ffff880669fba600 1869110148 S Co:2:002:0 s 23 01 0014 0002 0000 0
ffff880669fba600 1869110323 C Co:2:002:0 0 0
ffff880689ab3a00 1869166282 S Ci:2:000:0 s 80 06 0100 0000 0040 64 <
ffff880689ab3a00 1869166540 C Ci:2:000:0 0 8 = 12010002 00000008
ffff880689ab3a00 1869166555 S Co:2:002:0 s 23 03 0004 0002 0000 0
ffff880689ab3a00 1869179218 C Co:2:002:0 0 0
ffff880659512600 1869193914 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff880659512600 1869194130 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 03011000
ffff880659512600 1869194136 S Co:2:002:0 s 23 01 0014 0002 0000 0
ffff880659512600 1869194300 C Co:2:002:0 0 0
ffff88062d30ac00 1869265931 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0100 0000 0012 18 <
ffff88062d30ac00 1869292713 C Ci:2:007:0 0 18 = 12010002 00000008 6d0445c2 00690102 0001
ffff88062d30ac00 1869292737 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0600 0000 000a 10 <
ffff88062d30ac00 1869292876 C Ci:2:007:0 -32 0
ffff88062d30ac00 1869292891 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0600 0000 000a 10 <
ffff88062d30ac00 1869319555 C Ci:2:007:0 -32 0
ffff88062d30ac00 1869319582 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0600 0000 000a 10 <
ffff88062d30ac00 1869346174 C Ci:2:007:0 -32 0
ffff88062d30ac00 1869346188 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0200 0000 0009 9 <
ffff88062d30ac00 1869372903 C Ci:2:007:0 0 9 = 09023b00 020104a0 31
ffff88062d30ac00 1869372935 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0200 0000 003b 59 <
ffff88062d30ac00 1869373625 C Ci:2:007:0 0 59 = 09023b00 020104a0 31090400 00010301 02000921 10010001 22430007 05810308
ffff880689ab3000 1869373658 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0300 0000 00ff 255 <
ffff880689ab3000 1869373810 C Ci:2:007:0 0 4 = 04030904
ffff880689ab3000 1869373823 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0302 0409 00ff 255 <
ffff880689ab3000 1869374322 C Ci:2:007:0 0 36 = 24034700 61006d00 69006e00 67002000 4d006f00 75007300 65002000 47003400
ffff880689ab3000 1869374335 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0301 0409 00ff 255 <
ffff880689ab3000 1869374613 C Ci:2:007:0 0 18 = 12034c00 6f006700 69007400 65006300 6800
ffff880689ab3000 1869376264 S Co:2:007:0 s 00 09 0001 0000 0000 0
ffff880689ab3000 1869376420 C Co:2:007:0 0 0
ffff880659543000 1869376454 S Ci:2:007:0 s 80 06 0304 0409 00ff 255 <
ffff880659543000 1869376813 C Ci:2:007:0 0 26 = 1a035500 36003900 2e003000 30005f00 42003000 30003100 3000
ffff880659543000 1869376931 S Co:2:007:0 s 21 0a 0000 0000 0000 0
ffff880659543000 1869377023 C Co:2:007:0 0 0
ffff880659543000 1869377034 S Ci:2:007:0 s 81 06 2200 0000 0043 67 <
ffff880659543000 1869377765 C Ci:2:007:0 0 67 = 05010902 a1010901 a1000509 19012908 15002501 95087501 81020600 ff094095
ffff880621acaf00 1869378982 S Co:2:007:0 s 21 0a 0000 0001 0000 0
ffff880621acaf00 1869379108 C Co:2:007:0 -32 0
ffff880621acaf00 1869379136 S Ci:2:007:0 s 81 06 2200 0001 002a 42 <
ffff880621acaf00 1869379848 C Ci:2:007:0 0 42 = 0680ff09 80a10185 801a0038 2a073815 00250195 08750181 02852009 20950175
ffff88062d0bd300 1869380192 S Ci:2:007:0 s a1 01 0180 0001 0002 8 <
ffff88062d0bd300 1869380374 C Ci:2:007:0 0 2 = 8000
ffff88062d0bd300 1869380378 S Ci:2:007:0 s a1 01 0320 0001 0002 8 <
ffff88062d0bd300 1869380507 C Ci:2:007:0 0 2 = 2000
ffff88062d0bd300 1869380511 S Ci:2:007:0 s a1 01 038e 0001 0002 8 <
ffff88062d0bd300 1869380634 C Ci:2:007:0 0 2 = 8e03
ffff88062de85300 1869380935 S Ci:2:002:0 s a3 00 0000 0002 0004 4 <
ffff88062de85300 1869381094 C Ci:2:002:0 0 4 = 03010000
ffff880667cc5e00 1869399303 S Ii:2:007:1 -115:1 8 <
ffff880667cc5e00 1869466503 C Ii:2:007:1 -2:1 0
ffff880667cc5e00 1869527243 S Ii:2:007:1 -115:1 8 <
ffff880667cc5e00 1869614516 C Ii:2:007:1 -2:1 0
ffff880667cc5e00 1869631409 S Ii:2:007:1 -115:1 8 <
ffff8806e233f700 1875583178 C Ii:2:004:1 0:8 8 = 01000000 00000000
ffff8806e233f700 1875583238 S Ii:2:004:1 -115:8 8 <
ffff8806e233f700 1876543221 C Ii:2:004:1 0:8 8 = 01000600 00000000
ffff8806e233f700 1876543278 S Ii:2:004:1 -115:8 8 <
```

During this time, I moved the mouse and clicked its buttons with no events showing up.  *PLEASE NOTE*: this worked fine with openSUSE 42.1 and it works fine with OS/X Sierra. It does *NOT* work with openSUSE 42.3. I do not know about 42.2.

```
# modinfo usbcore|grep -i ver
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.85-22-default/kernel/drivers/usb/core/usbcore.ko
srcversion:     A8D8F77A295F278EE59630C
vermagic:       4.4.85-22-default SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Oh, yes, the dmesg stuff, too:

```
=== working correctly in rear USB port -- unplug

[11544.902225] usb 8-5: USB disconnect, device number 3

=== plugged into hub

[11549.503039] usb 2-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[11549.712271] usb 2-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c245
[11549.712287] usb 2-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[11549.712293] usb 2-2.3: Product: Gaming Mouse G400
[11549.712295] usb 2-2.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[11549.716170] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0/0003:046D:C245.0006/input/input15
[11549.716468] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.0006: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2.3/input0
[11549.718427] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.0007: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2.3/input1

=== not working -- removed from hub

[11562.094463] usb 2-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 5

=== plugged back into rear port

[11565.699196] usb 8-5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[11565.872150] usb 8-5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c245
[11565.872167] usb 8-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[11565.872170] usb 8-5: Product: Gaming Mouse G400
[11565.872172] usb 8-5: Manufacturer: Logitech
[11565.880790] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb8/8-5/8-5:1.0/0003:046D:C245.0008/input/input16
[11565.881100] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.0008: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:12.0-5/input0
[11565.888344] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.0009: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:12.0-5/input1

=== now it works again
```

=== Edit 2

evtest stuff:

```
# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 10 11:59 usb-Logitech_G500_AF1100EF1F0018-event-mouse -> ../event15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 10 11:59 usb-Logitech_G500_AF1100EF1F0018-if01-event-kbd -> ../event16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 10 11:59 usb-Logitech_G500_AF1100EF1F0018-mouse -> ../mouse1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 10 11:42 usb-Logitech_Gaming_Mouse_G400-event-mouse -> ../event2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 10 11:42 usb-Logitech_Gaming_Mouse_G400-mouse -> ../mouse0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 10 11:30 'usb-Microsoft_Natural'$'\302\256''_Ergonomic_Keyboard_4000-event-kbd' -> ../event3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 10 11:30 'usb-Microsoft_Natural'$'\302\256''_Ergonomic_Keyboard_4000-if01-event-kbd' -> ../event4
# evtest /dev/input/event15
Input driver version is 1.0.1 
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0xc068 version 0x111
Input device name: "Logitech G500" Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE)
    Event code 275 (BTN_SIDE)
    Event code 276 (BTN_EXTRA)
    Event code 277 (BTN_FORWARD)
    Event code 278 (BTN_BACK)
    Event code 279 (BTN_TASK)
    Event code 280 (?)
    Event code 281 (?)
    Event code 282 (?)
    Event code 283 (?)
    Event code 284 (?)
    Event code 285 (?)
    Event code 286 (?)
    Event code 287 (?)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
    Event code 8 (REL_WHEEL)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
[[[no input events logged]]] ^C


# evtest /dev/input/event16
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0xc068 version 0x111
Input device name: "Logitech G500"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 90 (KEY_KATAKANA)
    Event code 91 (KEY_HIRAGANA)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 121 (KEY_KPCOMMA)
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 129 (KEY_AGAIN)
    Event code 130 (KEY_PROPS)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 132 (KEY_FRONT)
    Event code 133 (KEY_COPY)
    Event code 134 (KEY_OPEN)
    Event code 135 (KEY_PASTE)
    Event code 136 (KEY_FIND)
    Event code 137 (KEY_CUT)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 139 (KEY_MENU)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 144 (KEY_FILE)
    Event code 150 (KEY_WWW)
    Event code 152 (KEY_SCREENLOCK)
    Event code 155 (KEY_MAIL)
    Event code 156 (KEY_BOOKMARKS)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 161 (KEY_EJECTCD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 167 (KEY_RECORD)
    Event code 168 (KEY_REWIND)
    Event code 169 (KEY_PHONE)
    Event code 171 (KEY_CONFIG)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 173 (KEY_REFRESH)
    Event code 174 (KEY_EXIT)
    Event code 176 (KEY_EDIT)
    Event code 177 (KEY_SCROLLUP)
    Event code 178 (KEY_SCROLLDOWN)
    Event code 181 (KEY_NEW)
    Event code 182 (KEY_REDO)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 187 (KEY_F17)
    Event code 188 (KEY_F18)
    Event code 189 (KEY_F19)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 194 (KEY_F24)
    Event code 206 (KEY_CLOSE)
    Event code 207 (KEY_PLAY)
    Event code 208 (KEY_FASTFORWARD)
    Event code 209 (KEY_BASSBOOST)
    Event code 210 (KEY_PRINT)
    Event code 212 (KEY_CAMERA)
    Event code 216 (KEY_CHAT)
    Event code 217 (KEY_SEARCH)
    Event code 219 (KEY_FINANCE)
    Event code 223 (KEY_CANCEL)
    Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
    Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
    Event code 228 (KEY_KBDILLUMTOGGLE)
    Event code 231 (KEY_SEND)
    Event code 232 (KEY_REPLY)
    Event code 233 (KEY_FORWARDMAIL)
    Event code 234 (KEY_SAVE)
    Event code 235 (KEY_DOCUMENTS)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 241 (KEY_VIDEO_NEXT)
    Event code 244 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_ZERO)
    Event code 256 (BTN_0)
    Event code 353 (KEY_SELECT)
    Event code 354 (KEY_GOTO)
    Event code 358 (KEY_INFO)
    Event code 362 (KEY_PROGRAM)
    Event code 366 (KEY_PVR)
    Event code 370 (KEY_SUBTITLE)
    Event code 372 (KEY_ZOOM)
    Event code 374 (KEY_KEYBOARD)
    Event code 376 (KEY_PC)
    Event code 377 (KEY_TV)
    Event code 378 (KEY_TV2)
    Event code 379 (KEY_VCR)
    Event code 380 (KEY_VCR2)
    Event code 381 (KEY_SAT)
    Event code 383 (KEY_CD)
    Event code 384 (KEY_TAPE)
    Event code 386 (KEY_TUNER)
    Event code 387 (KEY_PLAYER)
    Event code 389 (KEY_DVD)
    Event code 392 (KEY_AUDIO)
    Event code 393 (KEY_VIDEO)
    Event code 396 (KEY_MEMO)
    Event code 397 (KEY_CALENDAR)
    Event code 398 (KEY_RED)
    Event code 399 (KEY_GREEN)
    Event code 400 (KEY_YELLOW)
    Event code 401 (KEY_BLUE)
    Event code 402 (KEY_CHANNELUP)
    Event code 403 (KEY_CHANNELDOWN)
    Event code 405 (KEY_LAST)
    Event code 407 (KEY_NEXT)
    Event code 408 (KEY_RESTART)
    Event code 409 (KEY_SLOW)
    Event code 410 (KEY_SHUFFLE)
    Event code 412 (KEY_PREVIOUS)
    Event code 416 (KEY_VIDEOPHONE)
    Event code 417 (KEY_GAMES)
    Event code 418 (KEY_ZOOMIN)
    Event code 419 (KEY_ZOOMOUT)
    Event code 420 (KEY_ZOOMRESET)
    Event code 421 (KEY_WORDPROCESSOR)
    Event code 422 (KEY_EDITOR)
    Event code 423 (KEY_SPREADSHEET)
    Event code 424 (KEY_GRAPHICSEDITOR)
    Event code 425 (KEY_PRESENTATION)
    Event code 426 (KEY_DATABASE)
    Event code 427 (KEY_NEWS)
    Event code 428 (KEY_VOICEMAIL)
    Event code 429 (KEY_ADDRESSBOOK)
    Event code 430 (KEY_MESSENGER)
    Event code 431 (KEY_DISPLAYTOGGLE)
    Event code 432 (KEY_SPELLCHECK)
    Event code 433 (KEY_LOGOFF)
    Event code 439 (KEY_MEDIA_REPEAT)
    Event code 442 (KEY_IMAGES)
    Event code 576 (KEY_BUTTONCONFIG)
    Event code 577 (KEY_TASKMANAGER)
    Event code 578 (KEY_JOURNAL)
    Event code 579 (KEY_CONTROLPANEL)
    Event code 580 (KEY_APPSELECT)
    Event code 581 (KEY_SCREENSAVER)
    Event code 582 (KEY_VOICECOMMAND)
    Event code 592 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_MIN)
    Event code 593 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_MAX)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 32 (ABS_VOLUME)
      Value      0
      Min        1
      Max      652
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties: Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
[[[no input events logged]]] ^C

# evtest /dev/input/mouse1  evtest: can't get version:
Inappropriate ioctl for device /dev/input/by-id
```

Answer (score 0):

You debug from the lowest level up. You verify that the lower level work, then you look at the higher levels.

In principle, a mouse behind a hub should work out of the box, so I suspect a hardware problem with the hub.

The lowest level is USB: Look at the `dmesg` output when you connect the mouse directly and behind the hub (do `dmesg` before and after, the extra lines are the interesting ones, or look at the timestamp). Compare, look for errors, make sure in both cases `lsusb -v` provides the same information. If necessary, there are tools to do more debugging on this level (if it really turns out the hub is faulty). Editing the question with the `dmesg` output won't hurt.

The next level is the kernel input system: Both for the mouse behind the port and directly connected, run `evtest` as root, select the device, see if you get events if you move it. If the hub is defect, you might not get events for the mouse behind the hub here.

The final level is X. You already have looked at the log, and it does recognize the mouse, so I don't think the problem is on that level.

**Edit**

If there are no USB events with `usbmon` when you move the mouse while behind the hub, while there are such events when plugged in directly, then it's definitely an USB issue.

BTW, `event15` and `event16` as shown are from the *other* mouse (why do you have two mice? Or does the bug manifest in a spurious mouse?), you want `event2` in the given configuration, or just

```
evtest usb-Logitech_Gaming_Mouse_G400-event-mouse
```

But I expect the same behaviour as above for USB events (because no USB events -> no input events).

If it works with openSUSE 42.1 if behind the hub (compare `usbmon` behaviour), find the kernel version and file a regression bug with the kernel developers at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: I have two mice because one is plugged in where it doesn't work. :) One is a G400 and the other a G500. /dev/input/by-id tells you which device is associated with which event device. The G500 is the one not working and it is linked to event15, event16 and mouse1. For completeness, I ran evtest on all three. (P.S. for the sake of certainty, I also ran evtest on the G400 and the events all showed up just fine.)

Comment: I took your suggestion: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196897